# Call AWS API Gateway from .Net

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have setup an API Gateway with IAM_USER as authorizer. I also have cognito identity pool to get temporary credentials from aws, everything works great when I use API Gateway JS SDK. How do I make my calls from a C# .Net application with cognito identity?

Comment: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx3SGY7XYJ5KZRK/Amazon-Cognito-Credentials-Provider

Comment: Hi Jeff, it shows how to use cognito with AWS sdk for .Net calls, which is a good thing. Now, how to call API GATEWAY endpoint since it's not part of AWS SDK for .Net. if I am not wrong.